# Spinning wheel when using multiple iframes with Firebase in Safari

Tags: javascript, iframe, firebase, safari

Initializing a Firebase 3.6.4 app in three or more separate iframes on the same page causes Safari to give me the spinning wheel. Chrome and Firefox are okay.

I've reproduced the problem in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/talekhinezh/6g95Lpng/

iframe code @ https://talekhinezh.github.io:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyDY4SXY0wuwtoS6ZQpI7QhheIKD1PrrVQg",
            authDomain: "talekhinezh.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://talekhinezh.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "talekhinezh.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "202908208893"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
</body>
```

Host page code:

```
<iframe src="https://talekhinezh.github.io/"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://talekhinezh.github.io/"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://talekhinezh.github.io/"></iframe>
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: The same code seems to work for me now so it seems like firebase fixed it on their end.